# Making Shift-Scroll (horizonal) to vertical scrolling and CTRL-Left click (right click) to left click

Tags: macos, keyboard, mouse, scrolling

I like to play games on my Mac and one thing I noticed is that the scroll wheel wouldn't function when I was sprinting (Shift). Soon I figured out it was because of the horizontal scrolling feature on the MacOS system. Same thing with CTRL + Left Click. When I mean CTRL, I do not mean the (cmd) key.

Comment: The game itself ought to be able to handle that. Ask the developers.

Comment: @Tetsujin not many games handle that. That is why I am asking if there is a way I can do it from the system and not rely on the game developers.

Comment: 3rd Party mouse drivers can do it - USB Overdrive or SteerMouse if the game is being particularly poor at handling it -though I'm not much of a gamer, I've never found one that can't handle or work around standard Mac toolbox calls.

Comment: @Tetsujin I looked into USB Override and it doesn't have any of the logical conditions I need. Thanks for the suggestion though. I might as well play with these barriers until something is made in the future.